# Unable to omit null values in the json response in MF8 - using jackson annotations

Tags: java, jackson, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

Its good that MF offers options to get JSON in the response with ease. But the problem here is, I get all the properties in the response (including null values). I tried 2.x versions of Jackson to omit null values.

```
@JsonInclude
```

Still I get null values in the response.

MF doesn't provide Jackson and so I tried this by adding it as a maven dependency.

Is there a way to omit the not null values in here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
  @JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)

If you add this annotation on the class or on the getters for the specific fields you want to omit if they are null.

This worked for me with Jackson Annotations 2.5.0. I added this to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try in IBM MF8?

Comment: @Prisy - yes, I tried this in an adapter and it worked.

Comment: I tried with Jackson-annotations of versions 2.5 and 2.6. I am not able to omit null values in the response. Do you have any idea on how MF is supporting JSON conversions? May be we can check for compatibility.

Comment: I tried a simple get method to retrieve a few values.

`@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getbalance")
public Account getBalance(@QueryParam("accountid") String accId){
  
Account account = new Account;
account.setAccountNumber("ASA121");
account.setBalance("1000");
   
return account;
 }`

Comment: @Prisy - I am not sure what the issue is, it did work for me. Could you please post the code for the Acount class also and the pom.xml file in the question, so I can compare what you did with what I did and see where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Add @JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
above your class

Add following dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried 
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) - 2.6
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) - 2.5
Can you please share the jackson version?

Comment: in version 2.x+ the syntax for this annotation is:

@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) 
class Test {
  // ...
}

Comment: I am unable to resolve the compilation error. can you please share the dependency?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try in IBM MF8?